# Do not save the status frame after changing UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

There is a standard application tabBar.

TabBar1 and TabBar2

The controller TabBar2 has a UIButton and UITextField

UIButton run code

```
[textField setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 222, 320, 150)];
```

Works. And enter the text in the field.

Why when I switch to Tab1, and then back to switch to Tab2, the text state saved and the size is reset?

**SOLVED: Auto Layout is OFF**

Comment: It should not be. Unless maybe you initilize the layout in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. Both methods are called always when the view re-appers as well as when it appears for the first time. If so then move your initializations to viewDidLoad.

Comment: Thank you. How to be in my case?
I have a big form, I'm putting all the items in a UIScrollView.

In UIScrollView is also UITableView, table height is built according to the number of rows.

But as soon as I scroll UIScrollView or switching TabBar everything will be reset.

What to do in that case?

Comment: Don't know. I never tried adding a table view to a scroll view.